# Add the same value in multiple cells when parsing data to a spreadsheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Can I add the same value in two cells at the same line of code

I want to put "Run No." in the cell ["A1"] and ["B1"].

I could do this

```
sheet["A1"] = "Run No." 
sheet["B1"] = "Run No."
```

But I need to add this in many cells. I was thinking if I can create a list like this
list = ["A1","B1"]

```
sheet[list] = "Run No."
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Just use iter_rows, you can specify the start and end rows and start and end columns then just for each cell in the range set the value.
If it is just A1 and B1 then set the values as

```
first_row = 1
last_row = 1
start_col = 1
end_col = 2
```

---

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename = r"./book1.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

# Example Row 1 to Row 10 and Column A to Column T will be filled
first_row = 1
last_row = 10
start_col = 1
end_col = 20
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=first_row, max_row=last_row, min_col=start_col, max_col=end_col):
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = 'Run No.'

wb.save(filename)
```